# If I had known you ARE/WERE coming along, I wouldn't have gotten here really

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Let's your most hated person in the class suddenly popped up joining your group for a planned eating out. *Now* you are annoyed, and you said:

> If I had known you **ARE** coming along, I wouldn't have gotten here really

Or

> If I had known you **WERE** coming along, I wouldn't have gotten here really

This a 3rd conditional construction, after you applied (If I had) + participle, what is next? ARE or WERE

Comment: It's **were**. **I wouldn't have gotten here really** is slang and clumsy. You can either repeat **come** or say something like **I would have stayed away** https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third conditional does not apply to this situation since you are not going to explain two actions in the past which their sequence matters.

The correct form would be :

> If I knew you are/were comming...

Comment: Hehe nice, you're actually right.